# Not implementing interface member - C#

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error, and I am unsure what I am doing wrong.  Error 1 'Home.Services.InventoryImpl' does not implement interface member 'Home.Services.InventorySvc.CreateInventory(Home.Services.InventoryImpl)'

My Interface Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Home;
using Home.Domain;

namespace Home.Services
{
    public interface InventorySvc
    {
        void CreateInventory(InventoryImpl CreateTheInventory);
    }
}
```

My Implementation Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Home.Domain;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Home.Services
{
    public class InventoryImpl: InventorySvc
    {
        public void CreateTheInventory(CreateInventory createinventory)
        {

            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream
            ("CreateInventory.bin", FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write);
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(fileStream, createinventory);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Your method is called `CreateTheInventory` but in the interface it is called `CreateInventory`.  The method signature must exactly match the interface member in order for the compiler to treat that method as implementing the interface member, and the names do not match.

Further, the argument types do not match -- in your implementation you have `CreateInventory` as the argument type, but the interface takes an argument of type `InventoryImpl`.

If you correct these two errors, your code should build.

Comment: Agreed here, to add my two cents, after you type in your : InventorySvc, right click on the interface and select "Implement Interface", which will create your methods (and properties) as nessisary, then you just fill in the actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `InventorySvc` interface defines:

```
void CreateInventory(InventoryImpl CreateTheInventory);
```

But you have implemented:

```
public void CreateTheInventory(CreateInventory createinventory)
```

See the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature in the class does not match the interface method's signature.

Use the smart tag that appears when hovering with the mouse over the interface name, in order to create the interface implementation. This makes everything right for you.

Also, you should call your interface `IInventorySvc`. The guidelines for interface names state that an uppercase "I" should be placed before the logical name, even if the latter one starts with an "I".